# Rails 4 - footer rendered differently on index.html.erb and edit.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, materialize

If I render my footer.html.erb, I get different result on index.html.erb [image]

and new.html.erb,edit.html.erb.[image]

The application.html.erb:

```
<body>
 <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
 <div class="container">
  <%= yield %>
 </div>
 <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
</body>
```

The new.html.erb

```
<div class="row">
 <h3>Adding new property</h3>
 <%= render 'form' %>
 <div class="col s12">
  <%= link_to 'Back', properties_path %>
 </div>
</div>
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@property, html: { multipart: true }) do |f| %>
  <% if @property.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@property.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this property from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @property.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <form class="col s12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s4">
        <%= f.label :name %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
      </div>

      <div class="input-field col s4">
        <%= f.label "Rent or Sell" %><br>
        <%= f.select :rent, ['Rent', 'Sell']%>
      </div>

      <div class="input-field col s4">
        <%= f.label "Price in €" %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :price %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field cols s4"></div>
      <div class="input-field col s4">
        <%= f.submit "Submit", :class => "btn waves-effect waves-light" do%>
        <% end %>
      </div>
      <div class="input-field cols s4"></div>
    </div>
  </form>

<% end %>
```

I cannot see any reason why footer sometimes outside container div, sometimes inside. I use [materializecss.com](http://materializecss.com)

Comment: Can you show the `new.html.erb` view ?

Comment: Can you show the `_form.html.erb`? It looks like you might have a `div` tag that is left open in the form partial.